# Failed to Share Image using BlueTooth,Facebook using Content Provider in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

Following this [Tutorial to share Image From Assets Folder](http://www.nowherenearithaca.com/2012/03/too-easy-using-contentprovider-to-send.html). Please see previous post i have added code and everything there but the only problem I am facing is I am able to share image via Gmail while failed to share image in case of Bluetooth, Facebook. Can someone please let me know what is the reason ? In case of Bluetooth every time I am getting request but when I send image it response me `Fail to Sent`

[Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378738/failed-to-read-image-file-from-assets-folder-and-share-it-using-intent-in-androi/21379220?noredirect=1#comment32242800_21379220)